# Content Porting with permissions from a Publication

Tags: security, permissions, content-porter

Is it possible to export/import security settings of a publication using Content Porter (I'm using Content Porter and SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.1)

I have tried exporting and importing a *Publication Only* but it did not change the security settings.

Is there anything I am missing? or it is not possible to export/import the security settings of a publication?

Comment: I'd have to agree Mr Williams - good spot :)

Comment: Yeh. Although I think that you phrased the question more elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation ([2013](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8),  [Web8](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8)), it explicitly doesn't export *Permissions for Publications, Folders, and Structure Groups*